# Text box Action to Jump URL is not working

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have one ssrs 2008 report project, In this i have one column for displaying one link to connect the form. For that I have used Action property of the textbox. And I Appended my expression like this: `="javascript:void(window.open('" & Fields!ActionURL.Value & "'))"`. But unfortunately it doesn't render as a link. I dont know what went wrong with my code. Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: Does your ActionURL field start with `http://` can you show us the link ?

Comment: ya its start with http://. . the link like this:"http://serverName/Departments/Marketing/_layouts/xxx/Forms/Form.aspx?ItemID=51&Title=form - sps1_51"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

1) put the link path directly:

```
="javascript:void(window.open('http://servername/Departments/Marketing/
_layouts/xxx/Forms/Form.aspx?ItemID=51&Title=form'))"
```

2) try to open it in new window:

```
="javascript:void(window.open('http://servername/Departments/Marketing/_layouts
/xxx/Forms/Form.aspx?ItemID=51&Title=form','_blank','width=1250,height=1050'))"
```

P.S.
Double check your `Title=form` parameter , are your sure its current ?

**EDIT**

My suggestion is to store the parameter values only (and not the hole link path), this always works for me. Try the following:

```
="javascript:void(window.open('http://servername/Departments/Marketing/
    _layouts/xxx/Forms/Form.aspx?ItemID=" & Fields!ItemID.Value &
    "&Title=" & Fields!Title.Value & "','_blank','width=1250,height=1050'))"
```

**EDIT 2**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your post, Yes, If I try to add the link directly, It will work. But my problem is I have to add these links dynamically by specifying my column name (ie., ActionURL Field), because Each ItemID and title are different for each form.

Comment: It's Okay.. If the Server name Changes, what will do? there is no option for editing rdl files in Client's environment

Comment: You can edit RDL files directly from the reportserver's browser see attached image for example

Comment: Your answers makes sense. :-). May i know what's the problem while we pass the full url  value through dataset?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think that its related to the way that SSRS renders the queries.